# Hacer un Split hacia TextView al calcular edad

Tags: java, android

Tengo mi código para calcular la edad teniendo en cuenta los meses y día de la fecha de nacimiento, pero quiero hacer un split para enviar solamente el número de la edad hacía un TextView, pongo ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el TextView que quiero que salga es este:

> edad=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.edad);

Mi código,

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private Button btnStart;
    static final int DATE_START_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    private int startYear=1970;
    private int startMonth=6;
    private int startDay=15;
    private AgeCalculation age = null;
    private TextView currentDate;
    private TextView birthDate;
    private TextView result;
    TextView edad;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        age=new AgeCalculation();
        currentDate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        currentDate.setText("Current Date(DD/MM/YY) : "+age.getCurrentDate());
        birthDate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        edad=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.edad);
        btnStart=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_START_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        mDateSetListener,
                        startYear, startMonth, startDay);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener
            = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                              int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            startYear=selectedYear;
            startMonth=selectedMonth;
            startDay=selectedDay;
            age.setDateOfBirth(startYear, startMonth, startDay);
            birthDate.setText("Date of Birth(DD/MM/YY): "+selectedDay+":"+(startMonth+1)+":"+startYear);
            calculateAge();
        }
    };
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                showDialog(DATE_START_DIALOG_ID);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    private void calculateAge()
    {
        age.calcualteYear();
        age.calcualteMonth();
        age.calcualteDay();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "click the resulted button"+age.getResult() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        result.setText(age.getResult()+(" Años"));
    }
}
```

AgeCalculation:

```
public class AgeCalculation {
    private int startYear;
    private int startMonth;
    private int startDay;
    private int endYear;
    private int endMonth;
    private int endDay;
    private int resYear;
    private int resMonth;
    private int resDay;
    private Calendar end;
    public String getCurrentDate()
    {
        end=Calendar.getInstance();
        endYear=end.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        endMonth=end.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        endMonth++;
        endDay=end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return endDay+":"+endMonth+":"+endYear;
    }
    public void setDateOfBirth(int sYear, int sMonth, int sDay)
    {
        startYear=sYear;
        startMonth=sMonth;
        startMonth++;
        startDay=sDay;

    }
    public void calcualteYear()
    {
        resYear=endYear-startYear;

    }

    public void calcualteMonth()
    {
        if(endMonth>=startMonth)
        {
            resMonth= endMonth-startMonth;
        }
        else
        {
            resMonth=endMonth-startMonth;
            resMonth=12+resMonth;
            resYear--;
        }

    }
    public void  calcualteDay()
    {

        if(endDay>=startDay)
        {
            resDay= endDay-startDay;
        }
        else
        {
            resDay=endDay-startDay;
            resDay=30+resDay;
            if(resMonth==0)
            {
                resMonth=11;
                resYear--;
            }
            else
            {
                resMonth--;
            }

        }
    }

    public String getResult()
    {
        return resDay+":"+resMonth+":"+resYear;
    }

}
```

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Date Of Birth" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:text="Current Date"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Birth Date"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Result"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Edad"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edad"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Si es mejor con otro método que no sea con Split, comentadmelo, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te muestro como puedes usar el `split`:

```
String[] dayMonthYear = age.getResult().split(":");
String day = dayMonthYear[0];
String month= dayMonthYear[1];
String year = dayMonthYear[2];
edad.setText(year  + " Años");
```

Otra cosa que puedes hacer es un get de resYear al que puedes llamar después de hacer todos los calculos:

```
 public String getResYear()
  {
    return resYear;
  }

//...
     age.calcualteYear();
     age.calcualteMonth();
     age.calcualteDay();
     edad.setText(age.getResYear()+ " Años");
```

Saludos.

Comment: He visto que editaste tu respuesta, gracias por el split pero me parece más cómoda la primera opción que pusiste ya que para lo que quiero hacer luego me viene mejor, pero me da un error Android Studio. 'void' type not allowed here @FabioVenturiPastor

Comment: Si perdona fue fallo mio no me di cuenta que calcualteYear no devolvía nada, ahora te puse como hacer para que te devuelva el resultado.

Comment: El problema es que con la segunda opción no calcula bien la edad, es decir, no utiliza el mes y día, por lo tanto solo calcula el año de nacimiento @FabioVenturiPastor , pero usando el Split perfecto! te ha faltado añadir ; detrás de cada String, pero solucionado! Gracias !

Comment: Tienes toda la razón amigo, estar con varios lenguajes me tiene un poco loco... He editado de nuevo la respuesta, mira a ver si te sirve esa solución.